# Displaying a text box to show three lines

Tags: wpf, layout, textbox, font-size

I would like to make a WPF text box which is big enough to show 3 lines of text. So far, I have this code:

```
  System.Windows.Controls.TextBox myTextbox = new TextBox()
                {
                    AcceptsReturn = true,
                    MinLines = 3,
                    MaxLines = 3,
                    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"),
                    FontSize = 11,
                };
```

However, when `myTextBox` is laid out there is no guarantee that it gets enough height to show 3 lines of text. Ideally, I would like to specify the `FontSize` to be "so small that `myTextBox` has room for 3 lines of text, and no smaller". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This works for me and gives me exactly 3 lines of space. It must be a style or something else in your layout causing problems. Is the parent control constraining its height?

Comment: Yes, there is a layout context. Of course, I could try to make changes to the context instead of the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up simply putting the `TextBox` into a `ScrollViewer`, like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer myScrollViewer = 
    new ScrollViewer(){Content = myTextbox};
// Now place the ScrollViewer where the TextBox was before.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an illustration based on my comment above.

```
<Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto">
  <TextBox FontSize="11" MinLines="3" MaxLines="3" AcceptsReturn="True" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Border>
```

gives me three lines.

```
<Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="11">
  <TextBox FontSize="11" MinLines="3" MaxLines="3" AcceptsReturn="True" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Border>
```

only gives me one. The Border is constraining the height of the TextBox.